# why "ls -al" does not show file size info in /dev/socket directory?

Tags: adb, file-system

In /dev/socket directory, if runs "ls -al" in adb, there is no file size information.  I would like to know why there is no such information, in the condition that in other directories can show file size information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sockets and pipes represent Unix' way of inter process communication, and a communication channel has no point in having a size. Sockets are thus not seekable as in *go to position x in the file*.

Linux (which Android makes use of) has 7 file types:

- Regular Files
- Directories
- Character  Device Files
- Block Device Files
- Local Domain Sockets
- Named Pipes
- Symbolic Links

See more [here](http://bashshell.net/file-permissions-and-attributes/understanding-linux-file-types/)